# What does 0x8007007F mean when importing a function from an unmanaged DLL?

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, dllimport

I'm trying to import functions from an unmanaged DLL into my C# program.

This is my code:

```
[DllImport("MarkEzd.dll", EntryPoint = "lmc1_Initial2", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode,
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern int piplmc1_Initial(string PathName, bool TestMode);

....

int intlmc1_Initial = piplmc1_Initial(m_strEzCADSotwareFullPath, false);
if (intlmc1_Initial > 0)
{
   return;
}
```

The error is, translated from French:

> Unable to load DLL MarkEzd.dll, The Specified procedure can not be found Exception de HRESULT : 0x8007007F

What does this error mean?

Comment: Have you looked at www.pinvoke.net?  The kernal32.dll methods have sample code.  Only methods that are public can be accessed using DllImport.  Sometimes the names of the methods get change slightly so the DLL Export Viewer should give the correct names.  Make sure the dll are in the folder that is being used to compile.  You may have both a debug and a release folder and the dll must be in the proper folder.  Please post the error message you are getting.

Comment: The information in the question cannot be right. Error code 127 is `ERROR_PROC_NOT_FOUND` which you get after calling `GetProcAddress`. Furthermore, why would you call `LoadLibrary` to load the DLL but use a p/invoke for `piplmc1_Initial`, a function in that DLL. If you do the latter, then you don't need to explicitly use `LoadLibrary`, the framework handles that for you. It seems that you are not telling us the whole story. Please get the facts straight, and show a [mcve].

Comment: Hi, name seems to be correct regarding DLL Export Viewer, of course DLLs files are in the debug folder ( I use this folder only at the moment ).

Comment: By loading the library Lmc1 before, no error but no handle on hEzdDLL. I i don't load Lmc1, the message is in french but tells that an entry point cannot be found in dll Lmc1. **David**, as I wrote i'm not familier with librarys, for sure I do things wrong and i try to tell you the real whole story ;-) So i will remove the LoadLibrary and as you said the fisrt DLLImport is enough, it that means that this part is not OK...

Comment: We can't help you in detail if you only provide part of the picture. Please edit the question to get the facts accurate and complete. It looks like you've been hacking away, trying stuff at random, and posted some excerpt after that hacking. Often that trial and error just confuses us and makes your code worse! Details matter here.

Comment: So now, i removed the LoadLibrary functions and just leave the DllImport, when I execute it a got an error that tells ( in french ... )  unable to MarkEzd.Dll , The specified procedure can not be found HRESULT : 0x8007007F.

Comment: If you would do as I suggested, and make the changes to the question, it would be easily answered. But we can't answer a question only asked in comments. Do you know how to edit the original post?

Comment: **David**, I'm not hacking for sure, just try to use a library i get with a chinese laser without any documentation, yes i'm trying stuff at random because i don't know how to use a library, sorry if it is not clear, i will try to change the question but as you can see i don't really know what I'm doing so I can't be clear ... ;-)

Comment: By hacking, I mean trying stuff at random, trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you that the DLL that you loaded does not export a function named `lmc1_Initial2`.

You should double check the documentation for this library, and maybe it will be obvious where the error is. Perhaps a different DLL exports that function. Perhaps the name has been transcribed incorrectly. Note that letter case matters, so you must get all upper and lower case letters correct.

If the documentation does not help, use a tool like `dumpbin` or Dependency Walker to inspect the exported function names of the DLL.

Comment: OK so i will go back to my application and search for that. Something is stange, when I open Lmc1.dll I can see "public" or "protected" before each function but for MarkEzd.dll nothing in front, does that mean that function are not exported ?

Comment: When you open the DLL in what?

Comment: With Dependency Walker.

Comment: The list of exported functions is the complete list of exports, and the names are, well, the names. If the DLL developer stuffed private or protected on the front, or some name mangler did so, that's what the function is called.

Comment: Last question and then i will work on my side, this exception means that it can't find the function in the dll only or it can tell that the DllImport is wrong with the parameters types or conversion from C++ to C# ?

Comment: Only that the function is not exported. There's no way for the system to detect that your import is wrong. Although, name mangling and the stack imbalance MDA both can detect some signs of errors.

Comment: Do beware that the edits to the question have been very misleading.  The real problem is almost surely not the [DllImport] declaration, he can't load the DLL because it has a mismatch with another DLL it needs.  Being unable to find an export named CheckLaserState.  This isn't going to get better until he solves this DLL Hell and gets a proper set of DLLs from the supplier.

Comment: @HansPassant Except that what was originally claimed was that the DLL could not be loaded and the error returned on failure was `ERROR_PROC_NOT_FOUND`, which obviously cannot be accurate.

Comment: That's strange, now i just try to load the DLL with the dll import and use a simple function, this function just has to close a connection and return an int error code , I don't care that the function close anything for now, but I still get the same error , if a put a stupid name to the dll filename it is the same thing (0x8007007F), so even if the dll is paste everyware, it can't find it ... But I'm pretty sure that this dll exist ... mmmh I can open it with dllexp or Dependency Walker.

Comment: I can't debug this in comments. Perhaps you need a better understanding of how the system works.

Comment: @David, yes i need to go deeper for that, it is not simple to understand how it works really and what can be wrong. But really thank you to spend time for me even if i don't understant really what I'm doing, sorry for that. I'm loosing time but I will learn new things ...

Comment: @HansPassant I think you are right ... It seems that the first dll "MarkEzd" needs another dll "Lmc1", when I try to load it using LoadLibrary ( for test ), it tells me that it can't load a procedure from Lmc1.dll, it gives me the name and if I check with Depends there is a little difference in the name between the error message and the name in Depends, only 2 caractères, i saw it using "Undecorate C++ functions" option in Depends. So I assume that these two dlls mismatch and that's why I can't load it correctly. If I try DllImport directly with Lmc1 and the good name for entry point it works.

Comment: @David You was right two , it is obvious now !!! So I will try to get a library package from my customer.

Comment: It's frustrating that the facts that you reported don't tally with reality. This was a waste of everybody's time.